# matplotlib arrow gives ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am getting an error when I attempt to draw arrows using matplotlib's `arrow` function.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arrow_start = np.random.normal(0, 1, [100, 2])
>>> arrow_vector = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, [100, 2])
>>> plt.arrow(x=arrow_start[:, 0], y=arrow_start[:, 1], 
...           dx=arrow_vector[:, 0], dy=arrow_vector[:, 1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.2.2-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4844, in arrow
    a = mpatches.FancyArrow(x, y, dx, dy, **kwargs)
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-2.2.2-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\matplotlib\patches.py", line 1255, in __init__
    if not length:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This error message has very little to do with what is actually going wrong. I have given my own solution below, so others can learn from my debugging.

Answer (score 3):

The error message does not explain what's going on here: `matplotlib.pyplot.arrow` and associated `matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow`, `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow` do not support plotting more than one arrow at a time.

The issue is easily resolved with something like

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arrow_start = np.random.normal(0, 1, [100, 2])
>>> arrow_vector = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, [100, 2])
>>> for i in range(len(arrow_start.shape[0])):
...     plt.arrow(x=arrow_start[i, 0], y=arrow_start[i, 1], 
...               dx=arrow_vector[i, 0], dy=arrow_vector[i, 1])
```